# Swift Swagger-codegen. String to be sanitized is null

Tags: swift, swagger, swagger-codegen

I've faced with some issue using swagger-codegen

I receive many errors in console after:
`swagger-codegen generate -I ...net/api/v1/openapi.json -l swift5 -o /Developer/test`

Errors:

[image]

Example from .json file in swagger:
`"paths":{"/profile/getTransactions":{"get":{"tags":["Profile"],"summary":"","description":"","operationId":"get_profile_transactions_profile_getTransactions_get","security":[{"HTTPBearer":[]},{"OpenIdConnect":[]}],"parameters":[{"name":"page","in":"query","required":false,"schema":{"type":"integer","default":1,"title":"Page"}},{"name":"limit","in":"query","required":false,"schema":{"type":"integer","default":10,"title":"Limit"}},{"name":"start_period","in":"query","required":false,"schema":{"anyOf":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"null"}],"title":"Start Period"}},{"name":"end_period","in":"query","required":false,"schema":{"anyOf":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"null"}],"title":"End Period"}},{"name":"type","in":"query","required":false,"schema":{"anyOf":[{"$ref":"#/components/schemas/TransactionType"},{"type":"null"}],"title":"Type"}},{"name":"status_for_client","in":"query","required":false,"schema":{"anyOf":[{"$ref":"#/components/schemas/ClientTransactionStatus"},{"type":"null"}],"title":"Status For Client"}},{"name":"bch_code","in":"query","required":false,"schema":{"anyOf":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"null"}],"title":"Bch Code"}},{"name":"symbol","in":"query","required":false,"schema":{"anyOf":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"null"}],"title":"Symbol"}},{"name":"txid","in":"query","required":false,"schema":{"anyOf":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"null"}],"title":"Txid"}},{"name":"uid","in":"query","required":false,"schema":{"anyOf":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"null"}],"title":"Uid"}}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"Successful Response","content":{"application/json":{"schema":{"$ref":"#/components/schemas/PaginatedListResponse"}}}}`

I think that the problem in this line: `"schema":{"anyOf":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"null"}`.

As result I receive struct with fields like:

[image]

What I do wrong and how I can fix it ?
Swagger-codegen ver 3.0.54.